# onsen uiからjsonファイルをread/writeするリソースを探しています。

Tags: javascript, jquery, onsen-ui, angularjs, json

Jsonファイルをread/writeするクラスから
インスタンスしたオブジェクトを生成し、このオブジェクトに
readメソッドやwriteメソッドでファイルハンドリングすることを
想定しています。

オススメのものがありましたら、ご教授のほどお願い致します。

Comment: PCやスマホのブラウザで動くアプリを開発されているのか、Monacaアプリを開発されているのか、どちらでしょうか？

Comment: >PCやスマホのブラウザで動くアプリを開発されているのか、Monacaアプリを開発されているのか、どちらでしょうか？

前者の方です。

Comment: ブラウザで表示したWebページからPC上に存在するjsonファイルを読み書きしたいということですか。方法とかライブラリとか、もし既に調べたことがあれば教えていただけますか？

Comment: 基本スマホアプリなので、cordova-plugin-fileプラグインを
活用したものになるかと思います。

Comment: ブラウザで動くアプリというのは、ChromeやSafariで動くWebアプリの事を指して言ったのですが、そうではなく、（Monacaではないが）Cordovaを使ってアプリを開発している、ということですか？

Comment: Webアプリではなく、WebView上で動作するネイティブアプリのことです。

Comment: なるほど。Webアプリなのか、自前でWebViewを配置しているのか、Cordovaを使っているのかによって、回答が大きく変わってくるでしょうから、その辺りのことをタイトル、本文、タグに書かれると、回答者が見つかりやすいかと思います。OnsenUIはあくまで見た目を作り込むフレームワークですから、それよりもこちらの方が重要なキーワードだと思います。